# How do I pass the password in the URL for Jupyter?

Tags: python, authentication, jupyter-notebook, passwords

The jupyter has password based authentication setup.
This is set it the config file `jupyter_notebook_config.py`

```
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:SOME-SHA-VALUE'
```

I want to call the metrics endpoint which is exposed at `/jupyter/metrics`

The documentation indicates on how to pass token for token based authentication. I cannot find anything which specified how I can pass the password in the URL.

This does not seem to work:

```
curl -kv "https://my-domain/jupyter/metrics?password=MYPassword"
curl -kv "https://my-domain/jupyter/metrics?token=MYPassword"
```